# Extracting raster value to points in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I extracted my slope map to the points. I had to add the slope values to the points through extracted values to point but in the result's table of attribute I can't see any slope value. Can you help me with that?

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that 1) the values you are viewing are not valid NoData values from pixels outside your AOI? and 2) your raster and points have the same spatial reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tool  *Add Surface Information (3D Analyst)*. Remember to activate the Spatial analysis tools. It will create a new shapefile with the added information extracted from the raster.

Comment: The point is that my DEM is in UTM 18 N and my points are in WGS1984 and I need to add the elevation to that WGS1984 beside the Lat & Long. Should he layers be in the same coordinate system ?

Comment: Which EPSG projection are you using for your DEM? epsg 32618 ? My suggestion is to reproject the shapefile with the same EPSG used by the raster.

Comment: For this operation, you can use the *Project (Data Management)* tool.